# Haskell lookup table to return functions

Tags: haskell

Trying to extend "The Maybe monad" example on [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Advanced_monads) page.  Their lookup table `phonebook`:

```
phonebook :: [(String, String)]
phonebook = [ ("Bob",   "01788 665242"),
              ("Fred",  "01624 556442"),
              ("Alice", "01889 985333"),
              ("Jane",  "01732 187565") ]
```

and there chained monad examples:

```
getRegistrationNumber :: String       -- their name
                      -> Maybe String -- their registration number
getRegistrationNumber name = 
  lookup name phonebook >>= 
    (\number -> lookup number governmentalDatabase)
```

What happens if we want to return a function (that then returns a specific type) instead?  So extending from their example, instead of looking up a registration number, we want to lookup lookup either their age, their ZIP, or the years that there property taxes were paid.  Given these examples, an `INT` seems appropriate for the first two, and a `List of Ints` for the last.  **FIRST Question**:  since the lookup table has a type, must all of the return types of the functions be of the same type?  I am assuming yes, but am unsure, hence the next question.

lets say that we write these 'finding' functions that return the same type `[Int]`.  Maybe something like these:

```
getAge :: String -> Maybe [Int]
getAge phoneNumberString =
   lookup name phonebook >>==
      (\phoneNumberString -> lookup phoneNumberString governmentalAgeDatabase)
getZip :: String -> Maybe [Int]
getZip phoneNumberString =
   lookup name phonebook >>==
      (\phoneNumberString -> lookup phoneNumberString governmentalZipCodeDatabase)
getTaxPaidYears :: String -> Maybe [Int]
getTaxPaidYears phoneNumberString =
   lookup name phonebook >>==
      (\phoneNumberString -> lookup phoneNumberString governmentalTaxYearDatabase)
```

Now, assuming each of the the `*Database`s return an `[Int]` type, **Second Question** How do we write ONE function like `lookupPersonsInformation` that would return the appropriate information from what's typed in the input String, and given a lookup that returns the appropriate function, returns the information requested?   Here is what I am trying to make work:

```
lookupAppropriateFunction :: [(String, String -> [Int])] --Here I want the second part
                                                   -- of the tuple to be the functions
lookupAppropriateFunction = [ ("age",   getAge),
                              ("zip",   getZip),
                              ("taxes", getTaxPaidYears) ]

lookupPersonsInformation :: String -> Maybe [Int]
lookupPersonsInformation nameAndInfo =
   lookup ( words nameAndInfo!!0 ) >>=
     ( \phoneNumberString -> lookup ( words nameAndInfo!!1 ) lookupAppropriateFunction )

-- >> lookupPersonsInformation "Bob age"
      [53]  --Bob's age
-- >> lookupPersonsInformation "Fred zip"
      [28202]  --Fred's age
-- >> lookupPersonsInformation "Alice taxes"
      [2010,2011,2013]  --Alice's paid taxes years, It looks like she skipped 2012 :)
```

It is apparent that the errors propagate through to the end as `Nothing`, but I am unsure how to take the next step in applying this to a higher order function.   Is it more in the parsing using `words` or in the structure of the lookup table that I want to return a function`

Comment: Every person has an age, a zip code, and tax information (presumably). So `lookupPersonInfo` should have type `String -> Maybe PersonInfo` where `data PersonInfo = PersonInfo { personName :: String, personAge :: Int, personTaxYears :: [Int] }`. Then you have `fmap personAge (lookupPersonInfo "bob")`, `fmap personName (lookupPersonInfo "bob")`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with going with something like the following:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
intPusher :: String -> Stack -> Maybe Stack
-- ^ Takes a word, and tries to turn it into an Int, and push it onto the stack
intPusher word = case (reads word) of
  []       -> \stak -> Nothing
  [(x,"")] -> \stak -> Just (x:stak)
  [(x,y)]  -> \stak -> Nothing
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
dicLookup :: String -> Stack -> Maybe Stack
-- ^ Takes a word, and looks it up in the dictionary
dicLookup word = case (lookup word wordsTable) of
  Nothing -> intPusher word
  Just f  -> f
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
wordsTable :: [(String, Stack -> Maybe Stack)]
-- ^ Checks the string against the commands
wordsTable = [ ("+", addIt)
               ,("-", subIt)
               ,("*", multIt)
               ,("/", divIt)
               ,("/MOD", modQuotIt)
               ,("MOD", modIt)
               ....
               ,("2DROP", drop2It) ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
interpretProgram :: String -> Maybe Stack

interpretProgram str = foldl (>>=) (Just[]) (map dicLookup (words str))
```

and for each tuple value in the dictionary, I provided the function declaration:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
addIt :: Stack -> Maybe Stack
-- ^ Adds the first two elements of the stack
addIt stak = case stak of
  x:y:xs -> Just (x + y:xs)
  x:xs   -> Nothing
  _      -> Nothing
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
subIt :: Stack -> Maybe Stack
-- ^ Subtracts the first two elements of the stack
subIt stak = case stak of
  x:y:xs -> Just (y - x:xs)
  x:xs   -> Nothing
  _      -> Nothing
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
multIt :: Stack -> Maybe Stack
-- ^ Multiplies the first two elements of the stack
multIt stak = case stak of
  x:y:xs -> Just (x * y:xs)
  x:xs   -> Nothing
  _      -> Nothing

...
```

This works by taking a string, breaking it into individual 'words' (if possible, and returning `Nothing` if it can't) that are then passed into a dictionary to lookup the value of the word compared to the keys in the dictionary, thus acting like a lookup table.   If the word is a key in the dictionary, it returns the value, which is a higher order function that does certain tasks (just like the words function, if the higher order function encounters an error, it will return `Nothing`).

When dealing with Monads, there are only TWO types of return values. `Maybe AnyType` and `Nothing`.  An `AnyType` can be any type already declared in the module, or any basic type in Haskell (Int, Char, [Char], etc...).  The trick is to return either a `Maybe AnyType` or a `Nothing` type.  Since Haskell requires terminal declaration for if statements, it can be convention to 'catch' any potential errors and pass along the 'Nothing' type to the final return of a [grand]parent function.

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question you asked.